# What is the difference between pointer to 2D char array and pointer to 2D int array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, char-pointer

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        char str[3][15] = {"Pointer to","char","program"};
        char (*pt)[15] = str; // statement A
        char *p = (char *)str; // statement B
        printf("%s\n",p[3]); // statement C  - Seg Fault in this line
        printf("%s\n",p); // working properly displaying "Pointer to"
        printf("%s\n",p+1); // here it is pointing to second element of first array so displaying "ointer to"
        printf("%s\n",pt+1); // printing properly "char" as expected
        int num[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
        int (*nm)[3] = num[1];
        int *n = num;
        printf("n - %d\n",n[10]); // statement D
        printf("nm - %d\n",nm[0][0]);
        return 0;
    }
```

My questions:

1. Please help me to get clear idea about the data storing mechanism in
   case of char array and int array
2. In above program I am understanding that when pointer to char array
   is pointed to 2D array of char as shown in statement A it is
   displaying properly but when it is pointed by normal char pointer
   and trying to print the char in statement C it is getting SegFault,
   instead it should print 'n'(3rd number char in first array "Pointer
   to") so having confusion why in case int array i am getting proper
   element n = 11 in statement D and why in this case (statement C) it
   is not properly printing.
3. How the data will be stored in case of char array will it be stored
   in this form shown below

---

```
char str[3][15] = {{'P','o','i','n','t','e','r',' ','t','o'},
                   {'c','h','a','r'},
                   {'p','r','o','g','r','a','m'}};
```

if it is stored like this then it should work like array of integer pointer shown in statement D
Please help me to guide about this issue and clarify the issue I have in case of char and int array storage.

Comment: `char str[3][15] = {{'P','o','i','n','t','e','r',' ','t','o','\0'},
                   {'c','h','a','r', '\0'},
                   {'p','r','o','g','r','a','m', '\0'}};`

Comment: statement D works because `num` is getting allocated as a single array which the compiler accesses using the following formula: given the statement `num[row][col]` then it's the same as `*((int *)num + row * 4 + col)`.

Comment: `printf("%s\n",p[3]);` --> `printf("%s\n",&p[3]);`

Comment: statement B is the same as `p = str[0]` because how the array is being declared on the stack. `p[3]` returns a character, not an address as @LPs is noting. If you want to print `p[3]`, the format specifier should be `%c`.

Answer (score 4):

Lets look to your code step by step.

```
char str[3][15] = {"Pointer to","char","program"};
```

Here you have created an array of three arrays of fifteen `char`'s. And you are initializing each of the `char` arrays with string literals. If literals are shorter than array - last elements are filled with zeros, so it is the same as:

```
char str[3][15] = {
    {'P', 'o', 'i', 'n', 't', 'e', 'r', ' ', 't', 'o', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {'c', 'h', 'a', 'r', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    {'p', 'r', 'o', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'm', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

Then

```
char (*pt)[15] = str; // statement A
```

Here you create `pt` as a pointer to array of fifteen `char`'s, and you are initializing  it with address of `str[0]`, i.e. `pt` points to first `char[15]` array from `str`.

Next

```
char *p = (char *)str; // statement B
```

It is not OK. As far as I see - you are trying to make `p` to point to the first `char` at memory that `str` occupies. Expression `str` has type of `char (*)[15]`, i.e. it is a pointer to array of characters, not pointer to `char` (and because of this you are forced to use cast), And regardless to the fact that `str` really points to cell where the `'P'` is stored - you should to it in more type-safe way:

```
char *p = &str[0][0]; // the same as "p = str[0];"
```

`str[0]` is referencing to first element of `str`, i.e. type of `str[0]` is an array of fifteen `char`'s, then you can just refer to the first `char` and take it address - `&(str[0])[0]`, or simply use the fact that expression with type "array" decays to type "pointer to first array's element", that's why `str[0]` works too.

Lets go ahead

```
printf("%s\n",p[3]); // statement C  - Seg Fault in this line
```

This line causes undefined behavior, because format specifier requires the second argument to be a `const char *` but you are passing `char`. If you want to print one char - do that:

```
printf("%c\n", p[3]); // prints "n"
```

Then

```
    printf("%s\n",p); // working properly displaying "Pointer to"
    printf("%s\n",p+1); // here it is pointing to second element of first array so displaying "ointer to"
```

These work well, because the type of second argument is proper and we know that strings are nul-terminated.

```
printf("%s\n",pt+1); // printing properly "char" as expected
```

Saying frankly - it is incorrect, since `pt + 1` is "pointer to array of `char`" but you should pass "pointer to char". It should be rewritten as:

```
printf("%s\n",*(pt+1)); // or pt[1]
```

But it seems to work because regardless to the type incompatibility both pointers point to the same location.

Next section about `int`'s.

```
int num[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
int (*nm)[3] = num[1];
int *n = num;
```

Here are two mistakes: `nm` shouldn't be initialized with `num[1]` since they have incompatible types: "pointer to array of three `int`" vs. "array of four `int` / pointer to `int`" (thanks to decaying). And `n` can not be initialized with `num` because they have incompatible types too. According to my guess about what you want it should look in next way:

```
int num[3][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}};
int (*nm)[4] = num + 1;
int *n = &num[0][0];
```

And the last ones:

```
printf("n - %d\n",n[10]); // statement D
printf("nm - %d\n",nm[0][0]);
```

Dereference is correct and passed arguments too, but keep in mind that pointers were initialized incorrectly.

Hope, I've covered all your questions.

Comment: Great. better than mine. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your segfault is due to the fact that you are passing the wrong type to printf.

Writing `p[3]` you are deferencing the pointer to the 4th `char` of first row of matrix `str`. Same as `*(p+3)`

If you want to print the 3rd char you should

```
printf("%c\n",p[3]);
```

If you want to print the first C-String (row 0 of matrix) you must:

```
printf("%s\n",&p[3]);
```

because `%s` wants a `char *`.

If you add, at least for gcc, `-Wall` option to your command, compiler will show you a good and useful warning:

```
test.c:8:9: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         printf("%s\n",p[3]); // statement C  - Seg Fault in this line
```

---

About question 3 you must take note that the correct storing is:

```
char str[3][15] = {{'P','o','i','n','t','e','r',' ','t','o','\0'},
                   {'c','h','a','r','\0'},
                   {'p','r','o','g','r','a','m','\0'}};
```

due to the fact that C-String are null terminated, so, for example, the string `"Pointer to"` will occupy `11` chars

---

Last thing is about the `int` pointer. It works well because of `%d` format specifier wants an `int` value, not an address. So writing:

```
printf("n - %d\n",n[10]);
```

is fully correct because `n[10]` is dereferencing the 11th element of `num` matrix, that means 3rd element of 3rd row. Same as `*(n+10)`

Comment: *Writing p[3] you are deferencing the pointer to the 3rd char* That is not correct.

Comment: Using `p` to point out of the bounds of the inner array, such as `p[10]` is undefined behavior.

Comment: @2501 Ok for the first comment, I edited. But I'm not getting you about the second one.

Comment: Sorry I meant the pointer `n`. It's initialization is wrong, but if we ignore that, `n` is pointing to `num[0]` which is of type `int[4]`. Access `n[10]` is out of bounds.

Comment: @2501 I guessed it. Probably sunbathing on the seaside last days cooked my brain, but I really not getting you. `num` is a matrix `3x4`. Memory is contiguous, so starting from `&num[0][0]` there are 12 `int`s. So `n[10]` is inbound. Do I need coffee? ;)

Comment: Read 6.5 8 in the latest standard. Accessing an object out of bounds is undefined behavior. If there happens to be another object contiguous to this one is irrelevant.

Comment: @2501 Well, got it. But have you got an example where matrix rows are not contiguous and the behavior is really undefined?

Comment: The behavior is undefined because of 6.5 8. Whether the array is contiguous or not is irrelevant.